# How to update an SQL table based on the previous data in the same table

Tags: mysql, date, join

I have a table that measure the student performance `student` in my DB as below:

```
ID  TestDate    PerformanceStatus (PS)
1   15/03/2016  0
1   01/04/2016  2
1   05/05/2016  1
1   07/06/2016  1
2   15/03/2016  0
2   01/04/2016  2
2   05/05/2016  1
2   07/06/2016  3
2   23/08/2016  1
```

I want to update my table to have a new column PreviousPerformanceStatus. 
This PreviousPerformanceStatus is calculated based on the performanceStatus monitored, as below:
Note: If there is not performanceStatus recorded before the TestDate, I want to make the `PreviousPerformanceStatus = PerformanceStatus`

```
ID  TestDate    PS  PreviousPerformanceStatus
1   15/03/2016  0   0
1   01/04/2016  2   0
1   05/05/2016  1   2
1   07/06/2016  1   1
2   15/03/2016  0   0
2   01/04/2016  2   0
2   05/05/2016  1   2
2   07/06/2016  3   1
2   23/08/2016  1   3
```

How do I update my SQL table? Should I use join?
Thanks.

Comment: The logic is not clear (or possibly you have a typo).  Can you explain what the rules are?

Comment: Here's a tip:  first, write a query (a SELECT statement) that returns the result. And yes, a JOIN operation is one way to achieve the result. Or, you could use a correlated subquery. Once you have a SELECT statement, you can convert that into an UPDATE statement.

Comment: Let's use student with ID=1 for an example. The previousPerformanceStatus is calculated based on the PerformanceStatus from the "earlier" test date., so when TestDate=01/04/2016, I want to use the data from TestDate=15/03/2016. However, if I can't find any previous data, I will default the PreviousPerformanceStatus with the value in the PerformanceStatus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `testdate` column is `DATE` datatype (and not a VARCHAR)

And assuming that the `(id,testdate)` tuple is UNIQUE in `student`

We could use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list. As an example:

```
 SELECT t.id
      , t.testdate
      , t.performancestatus
      , ( SELECT p.performancestatus
            FROM student p
           WHERE p.id = t.id
             AND p.testdate < t.testdate
           ORDER BY p.testdate DESC
           LIMIT 1
        ) AS previousperformancestatus
 FROM student t
ORDER BY t.id, t.testdate
```

Once we confirm that the SELECT statement gives us the result we are looking for, we can convert that to an UPDATE statement.  Either as an inline view, or using the correlated subquery directly.

```
UPDATE student t
   SET t.previousperformancestatus
       = ( SELECT p.performancestatus
            FROM student p
           WHERE p.id = t.id
             AND p.testdate < t.testdate
           ORDER BY p.testdate DESC
           LIMIT 1
        )
```

If `testdate` is *not* `DATE` datatype, or is *not* stored in a canonical format, then then "less than" comparison is not guaranteed to restrict rows to an "earlier" testdate. And the "order by" is not guaranteed to return the most recent "earlier" testdate first.

For the "first" testdate, when there isn't an earlier testdate, the subquery will return NULL. We can use an expression to convert the NULL value to a 0. We could wrap the subquery in a function,  `IFNULL( <subquery> ,0)`

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT proposed by spencer7593 will work but is quite inneficient (in my case it took one minute in order to update three columns). The UPDATE will fail with an error telling you that you can not update a table that your are using in the FROM clause of the SET target.

[image]

Another, much more efficient way is to use a CTE with LAG() and to grab updated values from it. However, you will need a unique key to be used as the join key between the CTE and your table if there is no other simple or composite unique key.

```
-- Create the table as per question
drop table if exists student;

create table if not exists student (
pk int auto_increment,
id int not null,
TestDate date not null,
PerformanceStatus int not null,
PreviousPerformanceStatus int null default null,
primary key (pk)
) engine=innodb;

insert into student(id, TestDate, PerformanceStatus, PreviousPerformanceStatus)
values  (1, '2016-03-15', 0, null),
        (1, '2016-04-01', 2, null),
        (1, '2016-05-05', 1, null),
        (1, '2016-06-07', 1, null),
        (2, '2016-03-15', 0, null),
        (2, '2016-04-01', 2, null),
        (2, '2016-05-05', 1, null),
        (2, '2016-06-07', 3, null),
        (2, '2016-08-23', 1, null);


-- Update PreviousPerformanceStatus using lag()
with p as
(
    select pk, id, testdate, performancestatus, 
    LAG(performancestatus, 1, 0) OVER (
        PARTITION BY id
        ORDER BY id, testdate asc
    ) as PreviousPerformanceStatus
    from student
)
update student t
inner join p 
on p.pk = t.pk  
set     
t.PreviousPerformanceStatus = p.PreviousPerformanceStatus;
```

You can replace the third parameter of LAG() with null instead of zero.
I found this solution to be the most efficient among several other working solutions.