# Applying Lag query to new column

Tags: mysql, sql, lag, alter

Apologies for the green SQL question. I am applying this query to determine when there is a change in a PersonID, i.e. if the query return PersonID does not match the current PersonID then it is a new person instance. I want this query to alter the table to put the value in a new column, not just have the return in a query.

```
SELECT *,
       lag(PersonID, 1) OVER(ORDER BY PersonID ASC) AS test
  FROM Data_Temp
```

PersonID is the existing column, and test is the new column with `lag` values from PersonID

| PersonID | test |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

It has been suggested that I use `ALTER` to create the new column and apply the new data using `UPDATE` how should this be applied to the code above?

Comment: Can you show an example by mocking up a few rows of data that would require the change, and what it would look like after the proposed alter? I'm having trouble visualizing what you mean.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in an `ALTER` statement. You can use `ALTER` to add the new column, then `UPDATE` to fill in the column.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295293/simulating-lag-in-mysql-during-an-update for how to emulate `LAG()` in an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: @Barmar How would you apply `UPDATE` to the code above?

Comment: `UPDATE Data_Temp SET test = ...`. But you can't put `LAG()` there, so see the linked question for how to emulate it.

Comment: What if the next `PersonID` is `5`?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using the `CREATE VIEW` statement over the `SELECT`, that will allow you to replace the old table and avoid using `ALTER TABLE` and `UPDATE` statements.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Data_Temp_With_Lags AS
SELECT *,
       lag(PersonID, 1) OVER(ORDER BY PersonID ASC) AS test
FROM Data_Temp
```

Since this is a `VIEW`, data is computed only when you need it. If you want it stored, you need to change it into `TABLE`.

If this is a part of a bigger query, instead of creating a view or a table, you can store the `SELECT` inside a `WITH` clause.

More infos on common table expessions at this reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html.